# How do I mark a question as protected?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I would like to protect one of the questions, but there is no button for it. And documentation for this privilege is poor. I have over 15k reputation.

Comment: The vast majority of the time, explicit/manual protection is not necessary. The system automatically protects questions after 3 answers have been deleted from low-rep users, and possibly in other cases.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[They aren't poor, just short](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions):

> #### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege, provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation (such users would then be prevented from posting further answers after the question is protected).

So either the question is younger than 24 hours, or no users with less than 10 reputation have been posting answers. For your question, the latter was the case.

If the question *does* meet the criteria, you'll see a `protect` link next to the `share`, `edit` etc. links directly under the question body, like this:

[image: screenshot of (manually inserted) protect link beneath a question]

Comment: You are right, the question I care is not answered by users with less than 10 reputation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-to-add-toolbar-above-keyboard

Comment: OK, then based on events in the past, it isn't necessary to protect it, so you can't protect it now. This might change in the future, of course, when a new user *does* post an answer to that question.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk That question has not received a single *"Thanks"* or *"Me too"* answer so far, so why do you want to protect it in the first place?

Comment: A screen grab like that would have been sensible for the documentation.